# Sort by name in batch file

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file

I have a list of .sql files named by version

EG:
5.1.9.5.sql
5.2.1.5.sql
5.5.1.7.sql
5.10.6.2.sql

But when looping over them using:

```
for %%i in (*.sql) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

They come out in the following order:
5.1.9.5.sql
5.10.6.2.sql
5.2.1.5.sql
5.5.1.7.sql

Is there any way to get them to come out in the order listed first, which is like the windows file system? Without having to rename all the files.

Comment: First order is clearly not "correct" order - lexically 5.10 is less than 5.2.

Comment: Reworded the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to sort the problem by sorting the files by creation date.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /o:d *.sql') do (
    echo %%i
)
```

Comment: Only works because your releases-of-interest increase the numbers in the customary manner. It would break if you had a maintenance release of an earlier version (say 4.8.5.3.sql) appearing after the next main release.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever find yourself in a position where neither file creation date nor file last modified date help, then you could use my [JSORT.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595). It is a hybrid JScript/batch script that has an /N option that sorts numbers numerically instead of lexically. The utility is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.sql^|jsort /n') do (
  echo %%F
)
```